# Flexbox: Two boxes in the second row are positioned too far towards the outside

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The only thing which is wrong and should be different, is that the picture and text should be centered in the second row.

The two boxes in the second row are positioned too far towards the outside.

I want the two boxes in the second row centered exactly between the ones at the top

This is the previous code I created:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #666;
  justify-content: center;
}

.half {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100%/2);
}

.third {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100%/3);
}

.flex-container>* {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://img1.picload.org/image/dapawwpr/unbenannt.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://img1.picload.org/image/dapawwpr/unbenannt.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://img1.picload.org/image/dapawwpr/unbenannt.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="half">
      <img src="https://img1.picload.org/image/dapawwpr/unbenannt.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="half">
      <img src="https://img1.picload.org/image/dapawwpr/unbenannt.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: apply `.third` instead of `.half` to them also and then add `margin-left: auto;` to the last one

Comment: Can you explain why this will work?

Comment: first did you try it ? :) ... because if you do, you will see clearly why it will work ;)

Comment: I have now the result I want, but I dont understand why this worked?  https://jsfiddle.net/njzh4xy3/32/

Comment: first you make all the element same width since you applied .third on all of them ... then by default you have center alignment, but when you apply margin-left:auto to last one it will get pushed to right and you will have what you want ;) you can read more about how margin;auto works with flex